# problems to differentiate an expression

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I'm trying to differentiate this expression
$$-\frac{n}{2\sigma^2}+\frac{1}{2\sigma^4}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^2$$
along $\sigma$ evaulated at $(\mu,\sigma^2)$. I obtain $$\frac{n}{\sigma^3}-\frac{2}{\sigma^5}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^2$$
but the author obtains (see -2nd matrix in the snippet below)

$$\frac{n}{2}\sigma^{-4}-\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)^2\sigma^{-6}$$ and then
evaluated at $(\mu,\sigma^2)=(\bar{x},u)$ he obtains

$$\frac{-1}{2} nu^{-2}$$.

**Even if** his formula were correct, we should obtain $$\frac{n}{2}u^{-2}$$
and not $$-\frac{n}{2}u^{-2}.$$

Could someone make clear for me what's right and what's wrong ?

The snippet:

[image]

Comment: The differentiations are on $\sigma^2$, not $\sigma$. $\dfrac d{d\sigma^2}\dfrac1{\sigma^2}=-\dfrac1{(\sigma^2)^2}$. Then $\dfrac12-1=-\dfrac12$ and the minus sign is correct.

Comment: He is infant differentiating with respect to $\sigma^2$ not $\sigma$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author's calculations are correct. The author is differentiating wrt $\sigma^2$. Write $v:=\sigma^2$. In terms of $v$, the log likelihood is
$$
\log L = c - \frac n2 \log v -\frac1{2v}\sum(x_i-\mu)^2\tag1
$$
with derivative
$$
\frac{\partial \log L}{\partial v}=-\frac n{2v}+\frac1{2v^2}\sum(x_i-\mu)^2.\tag2
$$
Setting this last to zero and plugging $\mu:=\bar x$ yields $v=\frac1n\sum(x_i-\bar x)^2=:u$. Taking the second derivative of (2) and plugging in yields $-\frac12 nu^{-2}$.

Comment: We're maximizing the log likelihood (1) wrt both $\mu$ and $v$. This can be handled using calculus: (a) compute partial derivatives $\partial \log L/\partial\mu$ and $\partial\log L/\partial v$; (b) set both partial derivatives to zero; (c) solve the resulting equations for $\mu$ and $v$. I've omitted the equation involving $\partial\log L/\partial\mu$, which the author has solved to obtain $\mu:=\bar x$.

Comment: I have a small point yet: why do not we differentiate $-\frac{n}{2v}$ as a **composite** function i.e. as $\frac{n}{2}v^{-2}\cdot \dot{v}$ but rather without the $\dot{v}$ term ?

Comment: By $\dot{v}$ I mean $2\cdot \sigma$.

Comment: @user122424 We stop at $\frac n2 v^{-2}$ because we're still maximizing (1) with respect to $v$, not $\sigma$, hence we differentiate wrt $v$.